# How can i iterate through multiple DBs in python to SQL? is there a better way to do it than pyodbc.connect?

Tags: python, sql-server

ZMDB counter has multiple DBs stored in a list, and i want each to be passed through to Database using .format or some other method to iterate through DBs

```
import pyodbc
x = []
    def NMDretrievefunc():
        for each in ZMDBCounter(): #tells the list to pass in the database name below, each DB in the list
            conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                              'Server=alm-zm-sql;'
                              'Database={};'.format(each)#each is the DB name within the list
                              'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM [dbo].[InstNonMaturityDetail]')
                            for i in cursor:
                x.append(i)
        return x
```

Comment: Do you have a question?  At a glance `x = []` should be outside the `for each in ZMDBCounter()` loop.

Comment: And what is the problem with your code? You may not want to iterate off `cursor` object but its fetched results. And do you need *every* column?

Comment: thanks. it would be ideal to get as much information from the identically named table across DBs as possible, i just care that i can extract the columns from each of 300 differently named dbs on a server without having to type each db name...

Comment: @parfait? is there a better way to iterate Dbs? i have 300, i dont want to do manually haha, is there a better lib to import?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer

instead of

```
'Database={};'.format(each)#each is the DB name within the list
```

use

```
' f'Database={each};''
```